# How to detect that two songs on Spotify are the same (have similar name)

Tags: python, algorithm, levenshtein-distance

I'm using the following code to detect that two songs (same song, but different versions, e.g. typos, or concert variations) on `Spotify` are the same (have similar name). Is there a better (more intelligent) approach than checking if they have common beginning or `levenshtein distance`?
When I run that code, I have still duplicates, once in a while and have to delete them manually.

```
def similarity_old(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) != len(s2):
        return False

    count = 0
    for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2):
        if c1 == c2:
            count += 1

    similarity_percentage = (count / len(s1)) * 100
    return similarity_percentage > 70


def similarity_old2(s1, s2):
    # implements levenshtein distance
    m = len(s1)
    n = len(s2)
    if abs(m - n) > max(m, n) * 0.9:  # Allowing up to 90% length difference
        return False

    if s1 == s2:
        return True

    if m == 0 or n == 0:
        return False

    # Create a matrix to store the edit distances
    dp = [[0] * (n + 1) for _ in range(m + 1)]

    # Initialize the first row and column of the matrix
    for i in range(m + 1):
        dp[i][0] = i
    for j in range(n + 1):
        dp[0][j] = j

    # Compute the edit distances
    for i in range(1, m + 1):
        for j in range(1, n + 1):
            cost = 0 if s1[i - 1] == s2[j - 1] else 1
            dp[i][j] = min(dp[i - 1][j] + 1,  # Deletion
                           dp[i][j - 1] + 1,  # Insertion
                           dp[i - 1][j - 1] + cost)  # Substitution

    # Calculate the similarity percentage
    similarity_percentage = ((max(m, n) - dp[m][n]) / max(m, n)) * 100

    return similarity_percentage > 70

def similarity(s1, s2):
    # optimized levenshtein distance
    len1 = len(s1)
    len2 = len(s2)
    if abs(len1 - len2) > max(len1, len2) * 0.9:  # Allowing up to 90% length difference
        return False

    if s1 == s2:
        return True

    if len1 == 0 or len2 == 0:
        return False

    if len1 > len2:
        s1, s2 = s2, s1
        len1, len2 = len2, len1

    previous_row = list(range(len1 + 1))

    for i, c2 in enumerate(s2):
        current_row = [i + 1]
        for j, c1 in enumerate(s1):
            insertions = previous_row[j + 1] + 1
            deletions = current_row[j] + 1
            substitutions = previous_row[j] + (c1 != c2)
            current_row.append(min(insertions, deletions, substitutions))
        previous_row = current_row

    similarity_percentage = ((len1 - previous_row[-1]) / len1) * 100

    return similarity_percentage > 70


def common_beginning(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) > 11 and s2.startswith(s1[:11]):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def check_similarity(s, list1):
    # s = song name
    # list1 = list of song names
    # returns True if s is similar to something in list1, else False

    for item in list1:
        if common_beginning(s, item):
            return True
    #for item in list1:
    #    if similarity(s, item):
    #        return True
    return False
```

Comment: You can use embeddings similarity with very good results. Generate embeddings with a pre trained transformer, like BERT, then find cosine similarity / euclidean similarity between vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would tokenize the name, make all lowercase, filter out some words like "live, feat. ..." and then compute the difference so:

```py
IRRELEVANT_TOKENS = ["live", "feat.", "remix", "remastered"]

a1 = text1.lower()
b1 = text2.lower()

## redundant strings
a2 = a1
b2 = b1
for rm in IRRELEVANT_TOKENS:
    a2 = a2.replace(rm, "")
    b2 = b2.replace(rm, "")

a3 = a2.split(" ")
b3 = b2.split(" ")


if (len(set(a3) - set(b3)) == 0 or
    len(set(b3) - set(a3)) == 0):
    print("One contains the other, likely to be the same song")
else:
    print("Largely different, not likely to be the same song")
```

Code not tested, how do you make it take control of your Spotify?

PS: difflib might be a simple solution too.
But all solutions will either have false positives, false negatives or both, this is very difficult to automate!

Comment: Thank you, it doesn't need to be perfect. I'm using Spotify API, I adjusted [this](https://github.com/court-jus/spotimy/blob/master/spotimy/client.py) code. I changed the function `uniq`. That's how.

Comment: `if check_similarity(track["track"]["name"].lower(), [t["track"]["name"].lower() for t in plist_tracks[:idx]]):
                    to_remove.setdefault(track["track"]["id"], []).append(idx)`

Comment: But maybe you should add one condition yet, now it removes similar track names for different artists. But for me it's OK, the loss is less painful than duplicates.

Comment: Well that is true. There might be lots of similar names like "human" "love" "You" and so on

Comment: I meant it relating to the code in the comment. I haven't tried your code yet. I will try this evening, because I have to go out now. Probably I will have to expand the list of irrelevant tokens.

Comment: Yes of course, you'll have to fiddle around a little